# Clickable images (IMG's) but need the mouse icon to change over it

Tags: php, javascript, html, click

I have click-able images in my html page that call a javascript function... however nobody is clicking on them as they do not look click-able... how can I make them click-able without using an <a href=""></a> tag around it?

Here is an example of my code...

```
<div id="bvu11" style="margin: 0px 5px; float: left;">
     <span id="bviu11">
     <img src="/images/icons/favorites_add.png" onclick="favoritesAdd(2,11,'u')">
     </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Using CSS

Add a class to your image (ex: clickable-image) and this in your CSS:

```
.clickable-image
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the css [cursor](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp) property

```
<span id="bviu11" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

Comment: for goodness sake, don't add it as a style attribute.  add a class to the span, then put cursor: pointer in the class.  then you can change other style settings for this class in one place and your payload is smaller to boot.    .bviu { cursor: pointer }   ....  <span id="bviu11" class="bviu">

Comment: Style attributes are good when it's only applied to one thing. Any more and you should more it to a class.

Answer (score 1):

As well as adding the cursor:pointer, perhaps some styling to your images/buttons would also make them appear to be links before the user even has to hover over them. Try a simple border, or dropshadow/glow on the images to give them a more 3D effect, making them look more "clickable"! Also, adding a hover state (a different styling to the image/button) really helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<div id="bvu11" style="margin: 0px 5px; float: left;">
```

to

```
<div id="bvu11" class="spanLink">
```

and add

```
.spanLink {
   margin: 0px 5px; 
   float: left;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

to your css.